# Oracle JDK is no longer available/downloading from the webupd8team

Tags: ubuntu, java, apt, oracle

I had been depending on `ppa:webupd8team/java` to provide the apt package `oracle-java8-installer`.

The packages are no longer present: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/

What happened?

Answer (score 4):

Due to license changes by Oracle, the package maintainers have discontinued support for the Java installers.

Their announcement (effective April 16, 2019) is here:

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java